# keep track of already downloaded files with `alamofire`

Tags: swift, alamofire

how can i keep a track or record of already downloaded files in `alamofire` `swift 2.1` so that i don t have to download the same file again ? do we have any native method for that provided by `alamofire` or we have to do a check before downloading any file on our directory if we already have file with that name there ???? i'm confused on how to accomplish this with a proper approach

if anybody would clear my confusion about this then it'll be so helpful for me thanks

UPDATE:

```
        let documentsURL  = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let fileUrl = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(suggestedFileName)

    print(fileUrl)

    if !(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileUrl.path!)){

        self.suggestedFileName = (self.request?.response?.suggestedFilename)! // here how can i get the suggested download name before starting the download preocess ???

        print("\(destination)")
        request =  Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://contentserver.adobe.com/store/books/GeographyofBliss_oneChapter.epub", destination: destination)
            .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                print(totalBytesRead)






                // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
                // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead)")

                    self.progressView.setProgress(Float(totalBytesRead) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead), animated: true)
                }
            }
            .response { _, _, _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed with error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Downloaded file successfully")
                }
        }

    }else {


        print("file already exists")

    }
```

in the above update  am trying to get the `suggestedFileName` which is generated by `alamofire` but there's one problem when am trying to get `sugestedFileName` like this : `suggestedFileName = (request?.response?.suggestedFilename)!` in viewdidload am getting a null exception off course because there's no `suggestedFileName` because download not yet started so my question is that how can i get the `suggestedFileName` from `response` before starting the download ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading, you can download to a file. If your file destinations names are predictable, you could simply check to see if the contents of the file exists. For example if your are downloading data:

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: yourDestinationURL) {
  //Do your stuff here
}
else {
  //Download it
}
```

If you want consistency between names I suggest you avoid the Alamofire suggested destination and do this instead:

```
let path = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.ApplicationSupportDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
let newPath = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    Alamofire.download(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/stream/100", destination: { _ in
    newPath //You have to give the destination in this closure. We could say 'return newPath' instead, they're the same thing.
  })
  .progress({ _ in
    //progress stuff
  })
  .response { _, _, data, _ in
    //Handle response once it's all over
}
```

Comment: yeah i got the same workaround am trying to get the suggestedFileName  , but there's is one problem that i don't know how to handle please see my updated question

Comment: Yes you do have to do a check before every download. Alamofire does not provide a native way to do this.

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer again, I think you should be good to go. :)

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite "Alamofire does not provide a native way to do this". I totally agree with you and I think that this is un-acceptable for a networking library such as Alamofire, AFNetworking has this!